# Asignar un mismo objeto a diferentes variables en Java

Tags: java

Tengo una tres clases llamadas: Envio, Paquete y Dimensión. Un paquete tiene una dimensión y un Envío se compone de máximo tres paquetes.

paquete1
paquete2
paquete3

Tengo un método en envío que me está costando que es el de añadir/asignar un paquete a cada una de estas tres variables de arriba (cada paquete es diferente). Pero no se con que sentencia podría conseguirlo.

```
public class Envio {

private final double PRECIO_KILO = 2.2;
private Paquete paquete1;
private Paquete paquete2;
private Paquete paquete3;

public Envio()    {
    this.paquete1 = null;
    this.paquete2 = null;
    this.paquete3 = null;
}

public void addPaquete(Paquete paquete) {
    paquete1 = ????;
}
```

La clase Paquete

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Paquete {

private Random generador;
private Dimension dimension;
private double peso;


public Paquete()    {
    this.dimension = new Dimension(40,30,50);
    peso=8; //kg
}


public Paquete(double alto, double ancho, double largo)    {
    this.dimension = new Dimension(alto, ancho, largo);
    Random generador = new Random();
    peso = generador.nextInt(7) + 2;
}


public double calcularVolumen() {
   double volumen = dimension.getAlto()*dimension.getAncho()*dimension.getLargo(); 
   return volumen;
}


public double calcularPesoVolumetrico() {
   double pesoVolumen = this.calcularVolumen()/5000;
   return pesoVolumen;
}


public double calcularPesoFacturable() {
   double valorMayor;
    if(peso >= this.calcularPesoVolumetrico()){
       valorMayor = peso;
   } else {
       valorMayor = this.calcularPesoVolumetrico();
   }
   return valorMayor;
}


public Paquete obtenerCopia() {
   new Paquete();
   return this; 
}
```

Comment: El operador de asignación es el igual `=`. Eso es todo lo que se te puede decir sin ver tu código y con tu explicación. Tendrás que ser algo más concreto: mostrar el código y lo que pretendes hacer con él, lo que no entiendes o no te funciona, etc. Sino es imposible concretar más.

Comment: Gracias por el comentario, soy nuevo en el foro jaja. Ya añadí código. Saludos.

Comment: No somos un foro... qué falta de respeto. De todas maneras, dos cositas, primero que nada, cuando defines una variable de un objeto tuyo siempre va a ser `null` por defecto así que te sobra la parte del constructor: `this.paquete1 = ;this.paquete2 = null;this.paquete3 = null;`. Y lo que necesitas es basicamente comprobar cual de tus paquetes *NO* contiene un null, y guardarlo ahí: `if (this.paquete1 == null) this.paquete1 = paquete) else if (this.paquete2 ....`. Se pueden anidar `else if` hasta el infinito y más allá, y en este caso que tienes solo 3 variables va muy bien :)

Comment: Muchas gracias por la aclaración, ahora lo veo mucho mejor. Con lo del foro no pretendía ofender a nadie jaja.

Answer (score 0):

Existen los setters y getters,pero una manera mas sencilla seria crear un metodo void para asignar un solo objeto creado a tres variables diferentes seria de esta manera

```
public class Envio {

private final double PRECIO_KILO = 2.2;
private Paquete paquete1;
private Paquete paquete2;
private Paquete paquete3;

public Envio(){//constructor vacio solo para instancia la clase Envio

}

public void asignarPaquetes(Paquete paquete){
this.paquete1=paquete;
this.paquete2=paquete;
this.paquete3=paquete;
}

public String toString(){


return "Paquete1: "+this.paquete1+"\nPaquete2: "+this.paquete2+"\nPaquete3: "+this.paquete3;
}


}
```

en el constructor de tu clase paquete debe estar creado el objeto dimension el cual sera un parametro de tu clase paquete asi que no debe recibir ningun dato ya que los datos estan fijados

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Paquete {

private Dimension dimension;
private double peso;

public Paquete(){ //si quieres ingresar otras dimensiones solicita como parametro las variables de la clase Dimension;   
    this.dimension = new Dimension(40, 30, 50);
    Random generador = new Random();
    this.peso = generador.nextInt(7) + 2;
}


public double calcularVolumen() {
   double volumen = dimension.getAlto()*dimension.getAncho()*dimension.getLargo(); 
   return volumen;
}


public double calcularPesoVolumetrico() {
   double pesoVolumen = this.calcularVolumen()/5000;
   return pesoVolumen;
}


public double calcularPesoFacturable() {
   double valorMayor;
    if(peso >= this.calcularPesoVolumetrico()){
       valorMayor = peso;
   } else {
       valorMayor = this.calcularPesoVolumetrico();
   }
   return valorMayor;
}

public String toString(){
return "\nDimensiones: "+this.dimension+"\nPeso: "+this.peso+"\n";
}


}
```

tu clase Dimension tal cual

```
public class Dimension{

private double alto;
private double ancho;
private double largo;
 

 public Dimension(double alto,double ancho,double largo){

this.alto=alto;
this.ancho=ancho;
this.largo=largo;

 }
public double getLargo() {
    return largo;
}
 
public double getAncho() {
    return ancho;
}
 
public double getAlto() {
    return alto;
}
 
public String toString(){
return "\nAlto: "+this.alto+"\nAncho: "+this.ancho+"\nLargo: "+this.largo;

}
```

solo te queda instanciar todo y ejecutar

```
public class Main{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
   Paquete paquete=new Paquete();
   Envio envio=new Envio();


   envio.asignarPaquetes(paquete);

   System.out.println(envio.toString());

}
}
```

un solo objeto de la clase paquete  asignado a tres variables diferentes de un solo objeto de la clase Envio
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]